# How to load non-default models?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP2.x, I have frequently used `$uses` attribute in controllers but it seems that this attribute is no longer available in CakePHP 3.0.

The only way I know to load models which is not default one is to use `loadModel()` method. 
Is this recommended way to load models? Or is there any other way to load models?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your observations are correct, there is no `$uses` property anymore, instead models/tables that do not match the controller (ex `PostsTable` for `PostsController`) and are not available via associations, must be loaded explicitly.

This can be done by using either

- [**`Controller::loadModel()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake%5CController%5CController::loadModel) which adds the instance to the controller as a property.
- or  [**`TableRegistry::get()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class) which just returns the instance.
- and as of CakePHP 3.1 using [**`TableLocator::get()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Locator.TableLocator.html#_get), either by retrieving the locator via [**`TableRegistry::locator()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.TableRegistry.html#_locator) ([**`TableRegistry::getTableLocator()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.ORM.TableRegistry.html#_getTableLocator) as of CakePHP 3.5.0), or via [**`LocatorAwareTrait::tableLocator()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Locator.LocatorAwareTrait.html#_tableLocator) ([**`LocatorAwareTrait::getTableLocator()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.ORM.Locator.LocatorAwareTrait.html#_getTableLocator) as of CakePHP 3.5.0), which however usually shouldn't be required in a controller.

So this is kind of a yes to your question, `Controller::loadModel()`, ie

```
$this->loadModel('Name');
```

is a viable way of adding model/table instances to your controller as properties, wich at least in the default configuration, is essentially the shorthand for:

```
$this->Name = TableRegistry::get('Name');
```

but more `loadModel()` is more abstracted, and supports non-table repositories.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By the way, when I tried calling TableRegistry::get("Name") in constructor. I got an error saying "Call to a member function session() on a non-object". Am I not allowed to call the function in the constructor?

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki You probably forgot to invoke the parent constructor.

Comment: Is there any way to load multiple models using single statement in Cakephp 3?

Comment: @Sehdev No, all built-in methods for "loading" models load only a single model.