# table object and its associations in non related controller

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I have one controller say dashboardContoller, in that I want to fetch data from table class, but i'm not able to get table class object in `$this` object on that controller. I have observed that event manager is containing table object in old version of cake php2.7.

Currently I'm upgrading cake php 2.7 to 3.7 and in that I'm not able to fetch table from `$this` object.

Simply below code is not working in upgraded version

```
namespace app\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use App\Model\Entity\Group;
use App\Model\Entity\User;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class DashboardController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Users', 'Module', 'ModuleAccreditation', 'Reminder', 'BusinessRelationship', 'Document', 'Membership', 'Invoice');

    protected function _dashboardData() {
        $membershipStatusCount = $this->User->Membership->MembershipStatus->getCounts();
        $moduleAccreditationStatusCount = $this->ModuleAccreditation->ModuleAccreditationStatus->getCounts();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted your code sample so that's easier to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load non-default models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253989/how-to-load-non-default-models)